# Как сделать выезжающую панель поверх всех копонентов?

Tags: c#, winforms

В программе используется SplitContainer в вертикальной ориентации с разными компонентами. Мне нужно чтобы слева была панель/SplitContainer/любой другой компонент который будет по нажатию button как бы разворачиваться поверх SplitContainer и будет отображать button'ы (пример на рисунке).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, конечно, обойтись костылями вроде создать 2 панельки, одна будет свернутым вариантом, вторая просто расположена поверх всех обьектов на форме и в нужный момент ее ставить `Visible=true` у нее... но это не дело.

В конкретно даном случае -- тебе лучше писать свой собственный компонент под даную задачу. А как именно писать свой компонент -- уже изучай сам документацию в интернете. Ну а если будет вопрос по-конкретней... Тогда уже задавай его на SO.

Возможно, есть подобные готовые компоненты в интернете. поищи сначала по запросам вроде "C# collapsible panel" или подобных запросах.

Comment: Попробую поискать готовые компоненты. А что насчет костылей? Честно говоря может и подойдет. Можете поподробнее объяснить?

Comment: ну делаешь панель одну на которой нужные вещи размещаешь. Потом создаешь еще одну панель с продублированными этими же штуками, но с расширеной информацией, как тебе нужно. Выставляешь нужную ширину на этой второй паанели. И ресайзишь по высоте при ресайзе первой по высоте. Ну вот и весь костыль. сложно добавить что-то еще.

Comment: Я так понимаю вы имеете ввиду просто panel1 и panel2? Получается вторая панель должна быть по умолчанию скрыта и по нажатию она отобразится поверх всех компонентов.

Comment: да. Ну или не по нажатию, а наведению мышки на панель 1, или по нажатию на кнопку "раскрыть". Как удобнее)

Comment: Еще вопрос. Можно сделать так чтобы panel2 сама закрывалась при нажатии в любом другом месте кроме самой panel2?

Comment: ну.. да. Но лучше будет это делать, наверное, когда мышка с него уходит. Ну в плане OnMouseExit() иль как-то так